# Why PerMon Sever Agent listens only on tcp6?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

To start agent on server by executing the following command

```
$ ./startAgent.sh
```

> INFO    2018-03-27 18:31:04.981 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
>
> INFO    2018-03-27 18:31:05.982 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
>
> INFO    2018-03-27 18:31:05.986 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.0 started

To check its connectivity to this agent from other server, using telnet

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.31 4444
```

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 4444:Connect failed

if using ipv6 instead of ipv4, it can connect to that port.

```
$ telnet fe80::250:56ff:xxxx:xxxx 4444
```

Check the addresses and port, it only listens on tcp6, so that's why ipv6 can connect, ipv4 not.

```
$netstat -ano|grep 4444

tcp6       0      0 :::4444                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

udp6       0      0 :::4444                 :::*                                off (0.00/0/0)
```

My question is that why the server agent only listens on tcp6:4444 ? 
Is there any way to let him listen on ipv4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend `startAgent.sh` file and add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` line to it so it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar $(dirname $0)/CMDRunner.jar --tool PerfMonAgent "$@"
```

In order to play the same trick with JMeter add similar line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

References:

- [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)